# How to display more than 50 columns in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Im using phpMyAdmin 3.5.2.2

I have 70 columns in my table. But when I try to  browse using phpMyAdmin, only 50 columns will be display. Is there any way to have all the columns displayed.

Comment: execute this query, `select COUNT(*) totalColumns from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'yourdatabaseName' AND table_name = 'yourTable'` what is the result?

Comment: Structure your database better.

Comment: Add `limit 0,70` at the end of your query.

Comment: You may have entirely legitimate reasons for requiring a table comprising 70 columns but, frequently, this does point towards poor design.

Comment: @Strawberry I am hard-pressed to think of a scenario where having 70 columns is better than modelling the data via EAV. Could you provide an example?

Comment: Well, if I were to model up a replica of MS Outlook's contacts database, I might be tempted to do it as a table of ca. 120 columns, with separate tables for multiple addresses, contact numbers, etc. You're right, you could equally do this with EAV. I just don't like working with EAV.